# How to create a WinForms project that is "WPF-ready"

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, winforms

I'm a C# developer who hasn't had the privilege of learning WPF yet. However, I recently initiated the architecture phase of a new project which I expect will eventually employ WPF (probably; although ASP.Net is still an option) -- but the GUI development won't begin for *several* months. (We need to get buy-in on a WinForm-based proof-of-concept before we proceed with full production-grade development.) When we are ready to begin implementing the GUI, I will either learn WPF myself or hire someone with experience (preferably both).

So my question is, what are some key fundamentals (design patterns, language essentials, etc) that I could employ right away which would facilitate a smoother migration down the road? For example, my code is a simulation model which will contain a very large number of entities that will eventually need to be "visualized", with interactive user-controls. Are there certain techniques that, if implemented from the ground up, would make wiring up these objects with WPF less painful later on? (Like dependency properties, or what-not.) Similarly, if I stick with the MVC approach that I am familiar with for right now, will it be straight-forward to morph that into an MVVM strategy later? Are there some simple concepts that I could apply now that would make the migration easier, but which won't take two weeks out of my current dev-cycle to master?

Basically, I am trying to follow [Uncle Bob's advice](http://blog.8thlight.com/uncle-bob/2011/09/30/Screaming-Architecture.html) to postpone architectural decisions (in this case, the GUI layer) until I absolutely have to make them. But I want to know if there are any unnecessary migration costs that I could avoid if I anticipate them in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm glad you are already thinking about a MVVM pattern.  MVVM is very popular in WPF apps.  It is very likely if you are disciplined you can even implement your WinForms app with a MVVM approach.  If you do it will probably be as simple as implementing a the Views and maybe few new ViewModels if the UI designs are similar.

Basically encapsulation will be your friend.  No business logic in the WinForms project.  None at all.  Return basic models from your Core library and try to keep with WinForms as simple as binding models and then calling actions in your core class.

Comment: The only problem, that Winform's data-binding doesn't support "depth" binding - you cannot bind TextBox.Text to `ViewModel.SomeParent.Children.Name` - so you will end up with wrappers for every model -which can be kind of good thing from Law of Demeter point of view